# What role will WMT have within the ecosystem short term, but more so in the coming 5-10 years?

Tags: wallet, stake-pool, staking, yoroi, rewards

I would love a clearer picture of the integration of the world mobile token.
As well as short/long term plans, or specific goals that you guys might have?

Are there rivals/competitors in this niche? Including within the ADA ecosystem? I haven't seen one, if there are any, I'd love to see how they compare to each other. Please explain simply

Comment: This is not really the right place for the type of question you are asking.  Perhaps you and your friend can change it to fit in with the [guidelines for asking](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: It may be better to ask the same question in one of the [Cardano forums](https://forum.cardano.org/)